# Display Facebook Page Insights Publicly on Website Using Graph API without Requiring Login, Except for Owner

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am looking to integrate my Facebook Page Insights into my website using the Facebook Graph API. I want to make these insights publicly accessible without forcing visitors to log in, except for the page owner. Essentially, I'd like to display certain metrics and statistics from my Facebook Page to provide transparency and engagement to the public.

I have already explored the Facebook Graph API documentation, but I'm a bit confused about how to achieve this specific functionality. Here are my key requirements:

**Public Access**: I want to make sure that anyone visiting my website can view the aggregated metrics and statistics of my Facebook Page without having to log in or authenticate with Facebook.

**Page Owner Access**: As the page owner/admin, I would like to have a way to authenticate myself (via login, token, or any other method) to view more detailed insights that are not visible to the public.

**Data Display**: I am interested in displaying key metrics like post engagements, page likes, reach, impressions, and other publicly available insights.

**Automatic Updates**: Ideally, I would like the data on my website to be automatically updated periodically (e.g., daily) so that visitors can see up-to-date information without manual intervention.

**Security Considerations**: I understand that exposing API tokens or sensitive information on the client-side may pose security risks, so I'd like to know the best practices to keep the integration secure.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to achieve these requirements using the Facebook Graph API? Are there any specific API endpoints or access permissions I need to consider?

Comment: Insights are not publicly available, so having your visitors log into your app would not achieve anything to begin with. You need to get a page access token, via a page admin user account. _"I understand that exposing API tokens or sensitive information on the client-side may pose security risks, so I'd like to know the best practices to keep the integration secure."_ - by handling the API stuff on the server side ...

Comment: "Daily automatic updates" == cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access insights by getting long-lived page access token and it lasts about 60 days and your visitors don't need to login.
**Here is the documentation:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived#long-lived-page-token